# ¿cual seria el equivalente de input[type=radio]:checked en un checbox?

Tags: html, html5, css3

quiero darle diferente estilo cuando ya haya seleccionado el checkbox. con el radio boton pude hacerlo usando esto -> input[type=radio]:checked.

Comment: a que te refieres con diferente estilo?

Comment: que el icono del boton cambie cuando le doy click, pero no la marquita que viene por defecto sino personalizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El equivalente es este:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked
```

[Ver la pseudo variable `checked` en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

Comment: ah gracias era un poco ovbio jaja! ;)